# Need help understanding c++ .h file

Tags: c++, dll, unmanaged

I am trying to write a wrapper in C# for an unmanaged C/C++ dll I need to work with. In the process I am tring to kick the rust off of my very old C++ skills. In the .h file I see the code below.

```
png_demand_record_create(const char *name, const char* loc, int date, int quantity);
```

The first two parameters are srings and the second two are integers....right? I seem to remember in c there really is not a string but an array of characters, or the like. Isn't *name the pointer to the character array? Why in the second parameter is the * after the "r" in char and not before the "l' in loc??? Waht is the difference between those two parameters? Could it just by the typing of the author and it really does not matter?

Also, I am using a tool (Pinvoker) to help me write the C# wrapper for the call to the unmanaged dll (all I have is the .h file and the compiled dll). The tool gives me the following:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Some.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static png_demand_record_t png_demand_record_create([MarshalAs UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string name,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string loc, 
int date,
int quantity);
```

Looks to me as if the tool defines "name" and "loc" the same even though they are different in the .h file. Do I need to worry about this?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: They are exactly the same. `char* str` is the same as `char *str` is the same as `char*str` is the same as `char * str`, etc.

As for the C#, I'm afraid I can't be of much help there.

If you're interested, or if it's relevent, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling)'s the wikipedia page on c-strings (which is what you're dealing with here).

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between:

```
const char* loc
```

and

```
const char *loc
```

Some programmers prefer the former, to think of the `*` as part of the type. Some programmers prefer the latter, because the `*` is actually applied to only a single variable in this declaration:

```
char *foo,bar;
```

Only `foo` is a pointer in this case; `bar` is a simple `char`, nothing more. (That's why I prefer `char *foo`.)

Because they are identical in this case, they should be handled the same in your `Pinvoker` tool -- unless one of them is an *input* parameter and the other an *output* parameter, which can happen. Be sure to understand the API you're wrapping to make sure you know which ones are input and which ones are output -- and if any are *bidirectional*.

Answer (score 1):

1) Whitespace around `*` doesn't really matter, the both parameter types are identical.
2) Pinvoker marshals the parameters as follows:

```
...
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string name,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string loc, 
...
```

so, there's no difference either.